# R: How to to simulate ARIMA using starting values?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have built an ARIMA(p,d,q) model, m using say,

```
m <- Arima(ts.data, c(p,d,q))
```

Given some starting values, I want to simulate future values based on the model m. I can manually code it but there must be a way to simulate it. In `arima.sim` there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the starting values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Arima function from the forecast package to do this

```
new.starting.value <- c(0.5,0.55) # or any other value you want 
new.arima.object <- Arima(new.starting.value, model = arima.model.object)
# the simulate function will give you the simulated values
simulate.Arima(new.arima.object, nsim = 40, future = T) #this will simulate 40 periods into the future
```